# Image and Text in UITableViewRowAction

Tags: uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

i need to create a UITableViewRowAction but i need to have an image and the text centralized and the image view must come above the text. It should looks like the WhatsApp TableViewRowAction.

I've already used every kind of library that i've found in the internet to do it and i could not get success.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Hello, how did you end up doing?